# PS4 keeps turning on randomly

Tags: ps4

So last week I decided to play some games on my PS4. I played for about 2 hours and then turned it off because it was getting late. Then at about 3am in the morning my PS4 booted up. There was nobody around and the 'on' button was not stuck down. I decided that it was just a one-off and went back to sleep. The next morning at 3am again, My Ps4 Turned on again. What can I do to stop this from happening? It is very annoying, and I looked on the Sony help centre but there is no good reasons for why this is happening yet. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It's probably downloading and installing an automatic update to a game or the PlayStation 4 firmware. https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/games/installing--downloading---updating/how-to-set-up-auto-update-download-on-your-playstation-4/

Comment: Did you turn your PS4 completely off or did you put it into rest mode? Per the article @RossRidge linked, there is a setting where it will automatically turn on your PS4, if it is in rest mode, for updates

Comment: Is this an original PS4, Slim, or Pro?